# Pagination on archive.php page

Tags: query-posts, archives, pagination

I have an archive.php page with the following code:

```
<?php // Start your custom WP_query
$my_query = new WP_query();

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' ?> 1, 'paged' => $paged, 'category_name' => 'Casino Slots');
// Assign predefined $args to your query
$my_query->query($args);

// Run your normal loop
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?> 
Test 
<?php endwhile;
else :
// do stuff for no results
endif;

wp_pagenavi();

// RESET THE QUERY
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

and it displays the posts fine, but the pagination never shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that wp_pagenavi() is doing pagination based off of the global $wp_query instance instead instance you created.  You should either switch to using query_posts() to replace the global query instead, or use WordPress' built in [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) to output the paging.

Comment: +1 - I think this is similar to the problem i was describing here, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-archive-page-pagination-isnt-working